# How to extract the loading time of the landing page for each session in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I wish to have the loading time of the landing page for each session in bigquery by using this query:

```
SELECT
  sessionID, LandingPage, 
  first (hits.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime) as loadtime 
from(
  SELECT
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId,STRING(visitId)) AS sessionID,
    totals.transactions,
    hits.page.pagePath AS landingPage,
    hits.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime 
  FROM (
    SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId,
      hits.page.pagePath,
      hits.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime,
      MIN(hits.hitNumber) WITHIN RECORD AS firstHit,
      hits.hitNumber AS hitsNumber
FROM  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30'), TIMESTAMP('2017-06-01') )
WHERE
      hits.type = 'PAGE' )

  WHERE

    hitsNumber = firstHit)

GROUP BY

  sessionID, LandingPage
```

It is supposed to retrieve the only first hit in each session where the hit type is page.

But the value for loadtime is null for all the sessions. Does anyone know what cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the condition

WHERE
      hits.type = 'PAGE'

to

WHERE
      hits.type = 'EVENT'

As per GA Big Query documentation (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en):
When you query time-related fields (e.g., hits.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime), choose hits.type as Event if you want to use hit.type in your queries.